# How to fix integer overflow warning

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

I have some code that checks if an integer is within the range [−2^31 + 1, 2^31 − 1]. However, during compilation, an integer overflow warning is thrown.

```
long int tmp_l = strtol(tokens[8].c_str(),NULL,10);

if (tmp_l >= ( (int32_t)-1 * ( ((int32_t)1<<31) - (int32_t)1) ) && 
        tmp_l <= ( ((int32_t)1 << 31) - (int32_t)1) ) {

    long int in_range = tmp_l;

} else {
    cerr << "ERROR: int not in range. Expected [(-2^31)-1, (2^31)-1]. ";
    cerr << "Found: " << tmp_l << endl;
}
```

```
main.cpp:93:51: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
     if (tmp_l >= ((int32_t)-1 * (((int32_t)1<<31) - (int32_t)1) ) &&
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The code compiles fine and I have not seen a runtime error related to this warning. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5):

> Where am I going wrong?

2^31 - 1 is the largest integer representable by a 32 bit signed integer. Therefore the result of operation `1 << 31`, which is 2^31 is outside the range of representable values.

The behaviour of signed overflow is undefined.

> How to fix

You could use this instead:

```
if (tmp_l >= std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::min() + 1
 && tmp_l <= std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max()
```